# Problem in Flex integration with Blazeds using java

Tags: java, apache-flex, postgresql, flex4, blazeds

My name is Rahul.I am new to flex. I am trying to integrate flex with blazeds using java. I have written some code as per my knowledge. But it is not connecting to database. I am pasting my code here.Please look into this and let me know if i have done any mistakes over there:

My Flex code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.hello.vo.FeedbackVO;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        public function insertData():void
        {
            var feedbackvo:FeedbackVO = new FeedbackVO();
            feedbackvo.name = input_name.text;
            feedbackvo.number = input_number.text;
            feedbackvo.email = input_email.text;
            feedbackvo.feedback = input_feedback.text;
            ro.insertData(feedbackvo);
        }
        public function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(event.result));
        }
        public function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(event.fault));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:RemoteObject id="ro"
                    destination="feedback"
                    source="com.hello.Feedback"
                    endpoint="http://localhost:8082/Feedback/messagebroker/amf">
        <s:method name="insertData" 
                  result="onResult(event)"
                  fault="onFault(event)"/>
    </s:RemoteObject>
</fx:Declarations>  
    <s:BorderContainer x="0"
                       y="0"
                       width="100%"
                       height="100%">
        <s:Panel width="364"
                 height="333" x="206" y="83">
            <mx:Form x="0"
                     y="0"
                     width="100%"
                     height="100%">
                <mx:FormItem label="Name:">
                    <s:TextInput id="input_name" width="249"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="Number:">
                    <s:TextInput id="input_number" width="249"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="Email:">
                    <s:TextInput id="input_email" width="248"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="Feedback:">
                    <s:TextInput id="input_feedback" width="248" height="143"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem>
                    <s:Button id="insert_btn"
                              label="Insert Data"
                              click="insertData();"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
            </mx:Form>
        </s:Panel>
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

My Java Code:

FeedbackVO.java:

```
package com.hello.vo;

public class FeedbackVO
{
private String name;
private String number;
private String email;
private String feedback;

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public String getNumber() 
{
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(String number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
public String getEmail() 
{
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) 
{
    this.email = email;
}
public String getFeedback()
{
    return feedback;
}
public void setFeedback(String feedback) 
{
    this.feedback = feedback;
}   
}
```

Feedback.java:

```
package com.hello;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.hello.vo.FeedbackVO;

public class Feedback 
{

Connection connection;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

public Feedback()
{
    String host = "localhost";
    String port = "5432";
    String dbName = "test";
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName,"postgres", "admin");
        System.out.println("Database is connected");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String insertData(FeedbackVO feedbackvo)
{
    try
    {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT into feedback(name,number,email,feedback) VALUES ('" + feedbackvo.getName() + "','" + feedbackvo.getNumber() + "','" + feedbackvo.getEmail() + "','" + feedbackvo.getFeedback() +"')";
        if(stmt.execute(sql))
        {
            return "Thanks For your Valuable Feedback";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Sorry Your feedback is not entered";
}
}
```

If i try to execute the Feedback.mxml then i am getting "Sorry your feedback is not entered" as output.I dont know where the problem is.I think flex is connected successfully but problem is in java code.If anyone got an idea please help me.

Thanks a lot,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use logging (e.g. log4j, slf4j) in your server code to log your exceptions.
2. Instead of returning a message as result of `insertData()` you should return a success code or simply throw the exception. Both can be handled on the client side, where it's easier to show a localized message.
3. Use connection pooling and close your connection right after you finished your work.
4. Just define a local `Statement` variable and finally call [close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)
5. Make yourself familiar with [debugging web applications in Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing)
6. Use [executeUpdate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) and you error should go away. [execute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) returns `false` if the result is an update count and you are executing an `INSERT` statement so it will do so.

This would be my suggestion:

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    // get a connection from the connection pool
}

public int insertFeedback(FeedbackVO feedbackvo) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        try
        {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO feedback(name,number,email,feedback) " + 
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement();
            try
            {
                stmt.setString(1, feedbackvo.getName());
                stmt.setString(2, feedbackvo.getNumber());
                stmt.setString(3, feedbackvo.getEmail());
                stmt.setString(4, feedbackvo.getFeedback());
                return stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
            finally
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        log.error(e);
        throw e;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi splash, I am completely new in FLEX and JAVA. I need to create an application that integrate FLEX and JAVA. I want to know how it is possible. Which are the required software? Please reply me as early as possible. I am very eager to learn this thing.

Comment: @SagarRawal: A search on Google with "flex java" should direct you to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_java.html which is a very good compilation of Flex/Java development resources.

Answer (score 0):

Something went probably wrong with the INSERT. Hard to tell what (the basic syntax is ok) but by simply concatening strings it is vulnerable to special characters like quotes in the values passed into the query (and SQL injection attacks). Much better to use [Prepared Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Also those exception stack traces that are printed may contain useful information to resolve the problem.